# XSLT 1.0 - Padding 0's with Math Equation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to pad an output in XSLT with variables being multiplied in XSLT 1.0.  I cannot use the format-number because it will auto-round the numbers but I need to get the decimals in place.  I can get this to work when I use column formatting within the XML, but since this has multiple column formats within the value-of-select, it does not seem to work here and obey the 7 in the code below:

```
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(E_BaseRate * E_NormalHours * 2, 1, 7)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

The output I am getting is: 1601.93 translated to 160193 but I need to get the result of 0160193.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *"I cannot use the format-number because it will auto-round the numbers"* Please provide an example of such problem. A [mcve].

Comment: When using format-number: I get the result of: 0001602 which is the rounding result of: 0160193

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(E_BaseRate * E_NormalHours * 2, '0000000')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

Comment: So multiply by 200 instead of 2? It's not clear what the scope of the problem is. And your example is NOT a reproducible one.

Answer (score 0):

I broke this out to give you an idea.  You could use as is or put it all together into one select...

```
  <xsl:variable name="numToString" select="string(160193)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="numLen" select="string-length($numToString)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="value" select="concat(substring('0000000', 1, 7 - $numLen), $numToString)"/>
```